# How can I build a nondeterministic state monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, state-monad, non-deterministic

I want to build a nondeterministic state monad in Haskell. This will allow me to generate all the elements in my search space using the built up state to prune bad locations. Suppose I have the following (pseudo-)code:

```
primitives :: [State Int Element] 
primitives = [... list of primitive stateful elements ...]                                                                                                                      
combine :: Element -> Element -> State Int Element                                                                                                            
expand :: Depth -> [State Int Element]                                                                                                                        
expand 0 = primitives                                                                                                                                         
expand d = do                                                                                                                                                 
  ... do something to the state ...                                                                                                                           
  left <- expand (d-1)                                                                                                                                        
  right <- expand (d-1)                                                                                                                                       
  let out = combine left right                                                                                                                                
  guard ( ... some check on out ... )                                                                                                                         
  return out
```

There are several things here that don't work: the most basic thing that I need to understand is how to do something to state and then pipe it in to each of the `expand` branches. I've tried a bunch of ways with functions of type `State Int [ State Int Element]` but, ultimately, once I wrap the branches of the list monad in a state wrapper I can't remove it, right? So is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The StateT monad allows you to keep track of state while also making use of another monad, such as IO or Rand (for random values). If I've understood your question correctly, I think that StateT will solve your problem. Can you give an example of the kinds of things you want to have in the `primitives` array?

Comment: Sounds like LogicT monad transformer: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict with your nondeterministic state monad being `LogicT (State Int) Element`. Fair conjunctions, conditionals and pruning as a bonus. More efficient implementation than a simple list.

Comment: General note: do NOT build your own combined monads, use monad transformers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple `State` monad is defined as:

```
data State s a = State (s -> (a, s))
```

This represents a self-contained and deterministic stateful computation. Considering `[]` as a non-determinism monad, you can have `[State s a]` which represents a non-deterministic set of deterministic computations, or `State s [a]` which represents a deterministic computation producing a non-deterministic set of values. In neither case is any non-determinism present in the structure of the stateful computation itself.

To actually *combine* the state and non-determinism behaviors in the way you seem to want, you need to combine the two in a way that isn't possible using just `State`; this is the purpose of monad transformers. The type `StateT s [] a` is equivalent to:

```
data NonDetState s a = NonDetState (s -> [(a, s)])
```

What this gives you is non-determinism in the state value with only individual choices observable at any one point in the computation.

What this does *not* allow is any interaction between branches; state changes made in one branch will never be visible from other branches, which is what is generally desired in a non-deterministic computation.